# How can I sort a container based on std::tm?

Tags: c++, sorting, datetime, containers

I need to sort my custom class based on the `std struct tm` object. I would like to know if I am approaching this correctly and ask for suggestions for the comparison function. Originally, I was converting each `std::tm` member to some base number (like `Ticks` in .NET `DateTime`), but I thought that might be excessive.

I don't *have* to use a `list`, but I do have to use a `Container<MyClass*>`.  I would prefer the `list`, though. This is my custom class:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  std::tm _datetime;
  static bool ComparePointers(MyClass*& lhs, MyClass*& rhs);
};

bool MyClass::ComparePointers(MyClass*& lhs, MyClass*& rhs)
{
  // ??
}
```

This is my main function:

```
int main()
{
   std::list<MyClass*> classes;
   MyClass* class_1 = new MyClass();  classes.push_back(class_1);
   MyClass* class_2 = new MyClass();  classes.push_back(class_2);
   MyClass* class_3 = new MyClass();  classes.push_back(class_3);

   list.sort(MyClass::ComparePointers);
}
```

Comment: `MyClass* class_1();  classes.push_back(class_1);` Not part of your question, but I'm pretty sure this is wrong. Maybe you meant `MyClass* class_1 = new MyClass();  classes.push_back(class_1);`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks - I'll change the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mktime` to convert a `std::tm` value to a `time_t` which can be compared.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to convert the `std::tm` instance into an integral value, such as seconds since the epoch.  Do this for both objects in the `ComparePointers` function, then compare the values.

Another more complicated method is to compare each member of the `std::tm`, such as year, month, day, minutes, etc.

By the way, the comparison function is misnamed.  You are not comparing pointers, but time and date values.

Comment: I think the name is OK. It *does* compare pointers, but it defines that comparison in terms of the time/date data pointed to, in contrast with the "default" pointer comparison provided by `std::less<T*>` that only cares about the address. If you're only defining one comparison between pointers, you have the luxury of calling it `ComparePointers`. If you define more than one, you might need `ComparePointersByTime`, `ComparePointersByWeight`, etc.

Comment: Should probably do this during the variable initialization lest it be computed over and over during the sort?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ChristianAmmer, you can use [`mktime()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/) to convert [`tm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) to [`time_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/) for comparison. But since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), you can also use a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of defining a comparison function:

```
#include <list>
#include <ctime>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
public:
    // I added a constructor to initialize _datetime just for testing.
    MyClass() {
        time_t t = time(nullptr);
        _datetime = *localtime(&t);
        _datetime.tm_sec = rand() % 60;
    }
    tm _datetime;
};

int main() {
    list<unique_ptr<MyClass>> classes;
    classes.push_back(unique_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass));
    classes.push_back(unique_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass));
    classes.push_back(unique_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass));
    // C++14: classes.push_back(make_unique<MyClass>());

    classes.sort([](unique_ptr<MyClass>& a, unique_ptr<MyClass>& b) {
        return mktime(&a->_datetime) < mktime(&b->_datetime);
    });

    for (auto const &mc : classes)
        cout << asctime(&mc->_datetime);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Mon Jul 09 11:24:34 2018
>   Mon Jul 09 11:24:41 2018
>   Mon Jul 09 11:24:47 2018

Note 1: As an C++11 exercise, I replaced your raw pointers by instances of [`unique_ptr<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). This way, your example code no longer leaks the `MyClass` pointers on program exit.

Note 2: The function [`mktime()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/) might modify the passed `tm` struct. If this causes any issues, then you can copy the `tm` struct in the lambda expression first.

Note 3: I used the functions [`localtime()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/) and [`asctime()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/asctime/) just for demonstration. Recent Microsoft compilers consider them unsafe and suggest to use [`localtime_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye.aspx) and [`asctime_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6htak9c.aspx) instead.

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/PoAlOy)